# Rotations issues in ios6 - black screen

Tags: ipad, ios6, rotation

I found several problems with rotations in ios6 using iPAD...all of us...I resolved mostly all of them using the new method shouldAutorotate and shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation. But in one of the views is not updating properly the rotation. You can see (more or less) what happen:

[image: Rotation issue]

The top images describes the behaviour from landscape to portrait...if I change the rotation of my app in other different of the first image, and come back to the first tab, the app doesn't update properly the view in portrait.

The bottom images describes what happen when I am comming from portrait to landscape...in the last screen I can the half of the screen completely black.

My level in iOS is really basic I will like some tips...what do you think which could be the problem? because in other tabs is not happen of the same app it is not happen.

If you need a piece of code, let me know...thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reaction (ironic). I've discovered what was the problem with the rotation only in a particular screen of my app. The problem is that the one that built the app before me, used one `UISplitViewController` inside of a `UITabBarController`. This mix of `ViewController`, in iOS 6 bring a bunch of problems, specially with the rotations. After thousands of tries, I found this link and it is solved.

UISplitViewController inside UITabBarController in iOS6:
http://objectiveseesharp.wordpress.com/

That's all.

Should I change the title of the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
https://github.com/alexth/TBSV
Sample how to have NavigationBar, TabBar and SplitViewController in one project with correct looking transitions between orienations